# Prevent calling viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind for footer in iOS 10

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios10

It seems that something has changed regarding collection views in iOS 10. I'm using a collection view with a header but **no** footer. The collection view has no checkbox in `Accessories: Section Footer` and Footer Size is specifically set to `Width: 0, Height 0`.

I'm still getting a call to `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` with `kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`.

I've tried returning `CGSize.zero` from `referenceSizeForFooterInSection` with the same result (this method is getting called). Flow layout has also 0/0 set in the IB. Any ideas?

I've tested with iOS 10.0.1 and iOS 10.1.1.

Comment: That seems weird. Is the `referenceSizeForFooterInSection` method called? Are you sure you are not adding a footer either in your IB or through code? Is the footer size set to 0/0 on the Flow Layout in IB ?

Comment: This is really weird. I'll check the settings once again. `referenceSizeForFooterInSection` is getting called and I return `CGSize.zero`. I'm also setting footer size to 0/0 in Collection View Flow Layout in IB.

Comment: I'll try changing to a newer iOS.

Comment: Well I resolved this. It was due to an error in one of the prototype cells used: there was an accidentally added UICollectionView inside one of the prototype cells, which resulted in this weird behavior. Funny thing, is that in iOS 9 it works fine. :)

Comment: Makes sense! Glad you found it